# $\int \cos^2 (x\cdot \text{constant} )\, dx$ [Do I need to consider the constant?)

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm integrating $\cos^2 \left(\frac{\pi y}B\right) \,dy$, where $\frac{\pi}B$ is a constant.

Can I use this rule or does the face that I have a constant together with the X change the way of integration?

From the integral rule book form Rottmann

$$\int \cos^2 x \, dx = \frac12 \sin x \cos x+\frac{x}2+C$$

Comment: integrate as normal, but at the end divide by (π/b)

Comment: In general if you know an antiderivative of $f(x)$, then you also do of $f(ax+b)$, where $a$ is any non-zero constant and $b$ is any constant. Namely, if $F(x)$ is an antiderivative of $f(x)$, then $\frac{1}{a}F(ax+b)$ is an antiderivative of $f(ax+b)$. (i.e. to get $\int f(ax+b)\, dx$, replace every $x$ in the formula for the antiderivative of $f(x)$ by $ax+b$, and divide the whole thing by $a$. In your particular example $a =\frac{\pi}{B}$ and $b=0$.)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2527343/is-the-integral-of-sin2x-equal-to-both-sin2xc-and-frac12-cos2/2942343#2942343

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't inherently change the overall idea. What you're basically trying to do is

$$\int \cos^2(Ax)dx$$

where $A = \pi/B$ is a constant. Then it's sort of like the reverse chain rule. Since you know

$$\int \cos^2(x)dx = \frac 1 2 \sin(x)\cos(x) + \frac x 2 + C$$

Just let $x \mapsto Ax$ but also be sure to divide by $A$ to account for the antidifferentiation. Then we have

$$\int \cos^2(Ax)dx = \frac 1 {2A} \sin(Ax)\cos(Ax) + \frac{Ax}{2A} + \frac{C}{A} = \frac 1 {2A} \sin(Ax)\cos(Ax) + \frac{x}{2} +C $$

*(Note: slight abuse of notation there, since $C/A \ne C$. This is moreso just acknowledging that the constant of integration is arbitrary without initial conditions, so we can just replace the ratio of two constants, $C/A$, by another constant, and name it $C$ to appeal to our intuition on such matters.)*

---

This overarching idea can be verified by making the $u$-substitution $u=Ax \implies du = Adx$, giving

$$\int \cos^2(Ax)dx = \int \cos^2(u) \frac{du}{A} = \frac 1 A \int \cos^2(u)du$$

Answer (score 0):

To compute $\int \cos^2\left( cy\right)\, dy$, perform a substitution, $t=cy$, then $\frac{dt}{dy}=c$.

$$\int \cos^2\left( cy\right)\, dy = \frac1c\int \cos^2(t)\, dt$$

Now, you can use the formula and replace $t$ with $cy$ at the end.